# Replace direct RS485 to RS485 connection with Ethernet in the middle?

Tags: networking, ethernet, rs485

I have a RS-485 device connected via twisted pair to another RS-485 device.
I'd like to bridge the distance via Ethernet, like so:
`RS485 > Ethernet > RS485`

Is this possible with two RS485 to Ethernet converters?

`[RS485 device] to [RS485-Ethernet] via cable to [Ethernet-RS485] to RS485`

The RS-485 communication is bi-directional. As in, the master sends and asks for information. I thought of getting two USR-RS232-304 devices, which I'd like to use for this. Would these work for this purpose? What puzzles me is, one seems to be a server, the other client. Will this still allow for bi-directional comms on the RS-485 side?

I did read the manual, and while it describes the general setup of IP config and transmission parameters, I am not sure (or could not deduct from it), whether bidirectional RS485 would work or not.

Any diagrams I have seen show only one of these converters, with the other end being a virtual comport. The devices I have talking to each other are not computers, where I could load a virtual COM port; hence, my query.
Maybe someone has done exactly what I am after and can share.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://www.pusr.com/download/M0/USR-TCP232-304-User-Manual_V1.0.3.01.pdf, it should work.  I'd suggest speaking to their support staff directly.  (this was once (circa 1992) referred to as two "half bridges", setting to 255.255.255.255 would be a "dumb bridge")

Comment: Thanks have done so now... and maybe the answer it does not work; here another response, but referring to RS232 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410357/1815855

Comment: you definitely need a hardware sol'n; good luck  :-)

Comment: Well, I have contacted them three times and did not get a response. Last night a lighting strike took out the RS485 comms link. The problem persists. My question has been down-voted. Not sure why, as it describes the issue, and I could not find anything that answers it. The idea to use Ethernet, so that I could run the signal via fibre (not prone to lighting strikes).